# Placing authorize.net merchant seal in augular js view file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, authorize.net

I have angular js app with payment feature. I would like to insert authorize.net seal code (provided by authorize.net for verified merchants. I added my site to Verified Merchant Seal Domains List on authorize.net server):

```
<!-- (c) 2005, 2014. Authorize.Net is a registered trademark of CyberSource Corporation --> <div       class="AuthorizeNetSeal"> <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">var ANS_customer_id=my_customer_id;</script> <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//verify.authorize.net/anetseal/seal.js" ></script> <a href="http://www.authorize.net/" id="AuthorizeNetText" target="_blank">Merchant Services</a> </div>
```

when i inserted into one of my view page it shows the following error

```
Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.
```

i understand that, it cannot write the seal image after the view loaded (bcoz seal.js contains document.write code). but i don't have any idea how to resolve this.

If i placed this code in main index.html, it works fine (obviously). but i need it in one of my view file. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that document.writeln() will not run from your asynchronously loaded seal.js script as the page has already loaded. It is impossible to make document.writeln() and document.write() work asynchronously so you will have to work around it.

There are two solutions...

**The first solution** is to download the seal.js script and host it on your website, replace all document.writeln() functions with a string.

I have done this here (the seal.js file is in the js tab):
**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbxJEd**

replace `document.write()` and `document.writeln()` with

```
var htmlString = '';
htmlString += '<img src="blabla"/>';
```

**The second solution** (maybe the better option if you don't want to host the js) is to overwrite the `document.write()` and `document.writeln()` functions with your own....

**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoKvyg**

```
document.writeOld = document.write;
document.writelnOld = document.writeln;

//Getting the element we are rendering too and setting string and custom function
var placeholder = document.getElementById('sealPlaceholder'),
    sealHtml = '',
    customWriteFnc = function(html) {
        sealHtml += html;
        placeholder.innerHTML = sealHtml;
    }

//Overwriting document.write and document.writeln with our own function
document.write = customWriteFnc;
document.writeln = customWriteFnc;

//Loading the script after the page has loaded
setTimeout(function(){
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type= 'text/javascript';
   script.src= '//verify.authorize.net/anetseal/seal.js';
   head.appendChild(script);
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a directive I wrote for my project. Make sure to add my module as a dependency to your app.

Usage in your code:

```
<div data-authorize-net-seal="yourAuthorizeIdHere"></div>
```

Javascript:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  var ANSVerificationURL = "https://verify.authorize.net/anetseal/"; // String must start with "//" and end with "/"
  var AuthorizeNetSeal = {
    verification_parameters: "",
    id_parameter_name: "pid",
    url_parameter_name: "rurl",
    seal_image_file: (ANSVerificationURL + "images/secure90x72.gif"),
    seal_width: "90",
    seal_height: "72",
    seal_alt_text: "Authorize.Net Merchant - Click to Verify",
    display_url: "http://www.authorize.net/",
    text_color: "black",
    text_size: "9px",
    line_spacing: "10px",
    new_window_height: "430",
    new_window_width: "600",
    current_url: "",
    display_location: true,
    no_click: false,
    debug: false
  };

  var authorizeNetModule = angular.module("authorizeNet", []);
  authorizeNetModule.directive("authorizeNetSeal", [
    function() {
      var initialize = function(elem, authorizeCustomerId) {
        var innerHtml = "";
        AuthorizeNetSeal.verification_parameters = '?' + AuthorizeNetSeal.id_parameter_name + '=' + escape(authorizeCustomerId);
        if (window.location.href) {
          AuthorizeNetSeal.current_url = window.location.href;
        } else if (document.URL) {
          AuthorizeNetSeal.current_url = document.URL;
        }

        if (AuthorizeNetSeal.current_url) {
          AuthorizeNetSeal.verification_parameters += '&' + AuthorizeNetSeal.url_parameter_name + '=' + escape(AuthorizeNetSeal.current_url);
        }

        if (!AuthorizeNetSeal.no_click) {
          innerHtml += '<a ';
          innerHtml += 'href="' + ANSVerificationURL + AuthorizeNetSeal.verification_parameters + '" ';
          if (!AuthorizeNetSeal.debug) {
            innerHtml += 'onMouseOver="window.status=\'' + AuthorizeNetSeal.display_url + '\'; return true;" ';
            innerHtml += 'onMouseOut="window.status=\'\'; return true;" ';
            innerHtml += 'onClick="window.open(\'' + ANSVerificationURL + AuthorizeNetSeal.verification_parameters + '\',\'AuthorizeNetVerification\',\'';
            innerHtml += 'width=' + AuthorizeNetSeal.new_window_width;
            innerHtml += ',height=' + AuthorizeNetSeal.new_window_height;
            innerHtml += ',dependent=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes';
            innerHtml += ',menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,directories=no';
            if (AuthorizeNetSeal.display_location) {
              innerHtml += ',location=yes';
            }
            innerHtml += '\'); return false;" ';
          }
          innerHtml += 'target="_blank"';
          innerHtml += '>';
        }

        innerHtml += '<img src="' + AuthorizeNetSeal.seal_image_file + '" width="' + AuthorizeNetSeal.seal_width + '" height="' + AuthorizeNetSeal.seal_height + '" border="0" alt="' + AuthorizeNetSeal.seal_alt_text + '">';

        if (!AuthorizeNetSeal.no_click) {
          innerHtml += '</a>';
        }
        elem.html(innerHtml);
      };

      return {
        scope: false,
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          initialize(elem, attrs.authorizeNetSeal);
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
})(window.angular);
```

Answer (score 2):

The Authorize.net Merchant seal simply doesn't work. I wanted to go on record here and say that the script is useless. It is extremely outdated and doesn't do anything but confuse people and make a simple tag into something that uses a lot more resources than what it should.

Do yourselves a favor copy the link it outputs, remove the unnecessary parameters like height and width and be done.

```
<a href="https://verify.authorize.net/anetseal/?pid=theAnetIdThatTheScriptGenerates&rurl=https://yoursite.com/" onMouseOver="window.status='http://www.authorize.net/';return true;" onMouseOut="window.status='';return true;" onClick="window.open('https://verify.authorize.net/anetseal/?pid=theAnetIdThatTheScriptGenerates&rurl=https://yoursite.com/','AuthorizeNetVerification','width=600,height=430,dependent=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,directories=no,location=yes'); return false;" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"><img src="https://verify.authorize.net/anetseal/images/secure90x72.gif" alt="Authorize.Net Merchant - Click to Verify"></a>
```

Note that the script generates an id for you and it looks like:

```
var ANS_customer_id='XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX';
```

Just make pid that appears in the link, that number.

Trash the CSS in the style tags and unnecessary tag parameters.